# Postgres query for DISTINCT for either of 2 columns

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a messages table. As a side note all ids are UUIDs not INTs

```
messages
 - id
 - from_id
 - to_id
 - text
 - inserted_at
```

I want to retrieve the last message that was either sent or received by user x with every other user.

So given a table with this data

```
--------------------------------------------------
| id |  from_id  | to_id  |  text   | inserted_at |
--------------------------------------------------- 
| 1 |      1     |    2   |  hello  | 2020-01-01  |
| 2 |      2     |    1   |  sup    | 2020-01-02  |
| 3 |      1     |    3   |  hello  | 2020-01-01  |
| 4 |      2     |    3   |  howdy  | 2020-01-01  |
```

I want to retrieve the messages for user `1`.

Pseudo SQL

```
SELECT DISTINCT OR (from_id, to_id) text, inserted_at 
FROM messages 
WHERE from_id = 1 OR to_id = 1 
ORDER BY inserted_at;
```

The result should be:

```
--------------------------------------------------
| id |  from_id  | to_id  |  text   | inserted_at |
--------------------------------------------------- 
| 2 |      2     |    1   |  sup    | 2020-01-02  |
| 3 |      1     |    3   |  hello  | 2020-01-01  |
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `LEAST` and `GREATEST` to get the to/from tuples ordered:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ON (LEAST(from_id, to_id), GREATEST(from_id, to_id))
  from_id, to_id, text, inserted_at
FROM messages 
WHERE from_id = 1 OR to_id = 1 
ORDER BY LEAST(from_id, to_id), GREATEST(from_id, to_id), inserted_at;
```

Answer (score 2):

You can order messages for each user by partitioning your data by `LEAST(from_id, to_id), GREATEST(from_id, to_id)` and ordering by `inserted_at`, then you can select only the first rows from that set:

```sql
WITH CTE AS (
  SELECT *,
         ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY LEAST(from_id, to_id), GREATEST(from_id, to_id) ORDER BY inserted_at DESC) AS rn
  FROM messages
)
SELECT id, from_id, to_id, text, inserted_at
FROM CTE
WHERE (from_id = 1 OR to_id = 1)
  AND rn = 1
ORDER BY id
```

Output:

```
id  from_id     to_id   text    inserted_at
2   2           1       sup     2020-01-02T00:00:00.000Z
3   1           3       hello   2020-01-01T00:00:00.000Z
```

[Demo on db-fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/th2nzRN26pPf2tmqdRQjV3/0)

Comment: what if I'm using UUID for ids?

Comment: That should still work as both inputs just need to be the same datatype, and comparable.